# Source R into chunk

Tags: r, knitr, sweave, r-exams

I'm a new in `exams` so maybe this question is very newbie.

I can't `source` external `R`-file (contains re-usable functions) into my `.Rnw`.

MWE:

**functions.r**:

```
x <- 10
```

**question.Rnw**

```
<<echo=FALSE>>=
source('functions.r')
@
\begin{question}
  $x=\Sexpr{x}$
\end{question}
```

**generate.r**

```
library('exams')

exams2moodle('question.Rnw')
```

When I try `Rscript generate.r`:

```
Loading required namespace: rmarkdown

Error:  chunk 1 
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'functions.r': No such file or directory
Execution halted
```

How can I re-use own R-functions in some questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All exercises are copied to a temporary directory where they are processed. Thus, you are in a different directory when you make the `source()` call. So either you need to include it with the full path `source("/path/to/functions.r")` - or alternatively you can copy the file to the temporary directory. There is a convenience function `include_supplement()` to do the latter. If `functions.r` is in the same directory as `question.Rnw` you simply need to do:

```
include_supplement("functions.r")
source("functions.r")
```

in the code chunk at the beginning of `question.Rnw`.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Now I understand meaning of `tdir` :)